# Android signing keystore in project root

Tags: android

Is it a problem to store the "keystore" inside the root folder of an android project? Which elements get packaged inside the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the keystore somewhere other than the project folder. You don't want an unwanted person signing with your key.

And no it is not a problem, but it is not advised.

Comment: Thank you very much. So having the keystore in the project root will not lead to it being packaged inside the APK?

Comment: No it won't be packaged but that's not where you should keep it. please read http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html